# How do I call this function to randomly pick a number from a list and then combine "M",".", and ".wav" to make a file name?

Tags: python

So im doing a python mozart project where simpleaudio files are taken using code that randomly picks numbers from the list shown below to equal files name corresponding to a sound. I am having trouble finding a way to come up with code for this. The code under the funtion `minuet_filename` is what I have right now. I am pretty lost at this point. Here is the directions for this portion of the project.

*You are responsible for implementing four functions. The first function, minuet_filename(), takes one
argument, which is a string. That string will be the number of one of the entries randomly selected from
Mozart's minuet table. The function will return a string that is the filename for the corresponding audio file. Each minuet musical file begins with a capital "M", and then the number from the table, and then a period, ".", and then the file extension for the audio file, "wav".*

```
mm01 = [None, None, "96", "32", "69", "40", "148", "104", "152", "119", "98", "3", "54"]
mm02 = [None, None, "22", "6", "95", "17", "74", "157", "60", "84", "142", "87", "130"]
mm03 = [None, None, "141", "128", "158", "113", "163", "27", "171", "114", "42", "165", "10"]
mm04 = [None, None, "41", "63", "13", "85", "45", "167", "53", "50", "156", "61", "103"]
mm05 = [None, None, "105", "46", "153", "161", "80", "154", "99", "140", "75", "135", "28"]
mm06 = [None, None, "122", "46", "55", "2", "97", "68", "133", "86", "129", "47", "37"]
mm07 = [None, None, "11", "134", "110", "159", "36", "118", "21", "169", "62", "147", "37"]
mm08 = [None, None, "30", "81", "24", "100", "107", "91", "127", "94", "123", "33", "5"]
mm09 = [None, None, "70", "117", "66", "90", "25", "138", "16", "120", "65", "102", "35"]
mm10 = [None, None, "121", "39", "139", "176", "143", "71", "155", "88", "77", "4", "20"]
mm11 = [None, None, "26", "126", "15", "7", "64", "150", "57", "48", "19", "31", "108"]
mm12 = [None, None, "9", "56", "132", "34", "125", "29", "175", "166", "82", "164", "92"]
mm13 = [None, None, "112", "174", "73", "67", "76", "101", "43", "51", "137", "144", "12"]
mm14 = [None, None, "49", "18", "58", "160", "136", "162", "168", "115", "38", "59", "124"]
mm15 = [None, None, "109", "116", "145", "52", "1", "23", "89", "72", "149", "173", "44"]
mm16 = [None, None, "14", "83", "79", "170", "93", "151", "172", "111", "8", "78", "131"]

minuet_table = [mm01, mm02, mm03, mm04, mm05, mm06, mm07, mm08,
            mm09, mm10, mm11, mm12, mm13, mm14, mm15, mm16]

import random
import simpleaudio

def minuet_filename(mmid):
    print(random.choice(minuet_table))
    return (random.choice(minuet_table))

roll = minuet_filename
print(roll)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what the instructions you provide describe:

```
def minuet_filename(mmid):
    return 'M' + mmid + '.wav'

def random_number_from_tables():
    return random.choice(random.choice(minuet_table)[2:])

number = random_number_from_tables()
print(minuet_filename(number))
```

Results look like this (one at a time):

```
M158.wav
M109.wav
M68.wav
M160.wav
```